# Char array size ? Stringbuffer to save an HTMl file in a string

Tags: java, string, url

I am reading an HTML file and saving it in a string.  I wanted to read the length (`int len = con.getcontentlength()`) and put char `charArray=new char(len)` but the result of `getContentLength` is always -1.
So I fix the charArray but if I put 
    `char[] charArray=new char[1]`  or 
    `char[] charArray=new char[512]`  or
    `char[] charArray=new char[1024]`

it always works.

I don't understand why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String name="AAAA";     
    URL url = new URL("http:...");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

    int numCharsRead;   
    char[] charArray = new char[1];
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0)
        sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
    String htmlString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: don't use StringBuffer unless your program is multithreading. use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Ok thx i changed to Stringbuilder but the charArray ? i can put the dimension i want

Answer (score 3):

Change from `new char[1];` to `new char[isr.available()];`

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    int c = 0;
    while((c = isr.read()) != -1) {
        char character = (char) c;

        System.out.println(character);

    }
```